# Know if app is installed for "All users"

Tags: c#, .net

How do detect if my app was installed for "All users" or just for one user.

Today I check for files put in either `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData` or `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` by my installer.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To expand on Sachin Gaur's answer:

The S-1-5-18<sup>**(*)**</sup> folder is for Local System user - which is used when installing for All Users.
Intallation for the current user would have the product key in a folder named after that user's security identifier (S-something-else).

To get the current user's SID, use [`System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.getcurrent.aspx) to get a [`WindowsIdentity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.aspx). Then, use the [`User`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.user.aspx) property to get a [`SecurityIdentifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.securityidentifier.aspx). Then use [`ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.securityidentifier.tostring.aspx) to get the string value.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.getvalue.aspx) for the GetValue method used to access the registry.

<sup>**(*)**</sup> `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\`

Answer (score 1):

I hope this may be useful to you.

You can know whether application is installed for all user or not by reading the registry value. For this, you must know the product code of the application:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\

To read the registry entry in C#, you can use **GetValue()** method of **Registry** class in Microsoft.Win32.